# is it possible to create trigger without execute procedure in postgresql?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

i want to create procedure with BL in its body. i find the same example in SQL but not in postgresql.

Comment: No, this is not possible in Postgres (btw: what do you mean with "*example in SQL*"?  - triggers are different for every DBMS, "*SQL*" is just a query language, not a DBMS product)

Comment: *PostgreSQL only allows the execution of a user-defined function for the triggered action. The standard allows the execution of a number of other SQL commands, such as CREATE TABLE, as the triggered action. **This limitation is not hard to work around by creating a user-defined function that executes the desired commands.*** http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: i mean i did same thing in sql but now am working in postgresql and am not able to do in postgresql and can't find example like that so is it possible?

Comment: Again: what do you mean with "*in SQL*"? `SQL` is **just a query language**. But the bottom line is: you simply can't do that in Postgres. See the examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Every RDBMS have their own SQL language. You can't create trigger in PostgreSQL as you can create in Oracle/MS SQL etc. In order to create trigger in PostgreSQL you have to

1. Create a function in PostgreSQL with you BL
2. Create a trigger and associate your function with this trigger.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible - PostgreSQL doesn't support SQL triggers - every trigger needs a related trigger function. Other databases supports SQL triggers only, but not PostgreSQL.