# Create or replace trigger postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, database-trigger

I want to "create or replace" a trigger for a postgres table. However, there is not such sql expression.

I see that I can do a "`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS`" first (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-droptrigger.html).

My question are:

1. Is there a recommended/better option than (`DROP` + `CREATE` trigger)
2. Is there a reason why there is not such "create or replace trigger" (which might imply that I should not be wanting to do it)

Note that there is a "`Create or Replace Trigger`" in oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm). Then,

3. Is such command planned for Postgres at all?

Comment: I'm coming from the future :D since version 14 there is OR REPLACE clause for CREATE TRIGGER -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Postgresql has transaction DDL so `BEGIN > DROP > CREATE > COMMIT` is the equivalent of `CREATE OR REPLACE`

[This](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis) is a nice write-up of how postgre's transactional DDL compares to other systems (such as oracle)

Current postgres planned features regarding [triggers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Triggers) do not include adding the `REPLACE` syntax.

Comment: why does postgreql allow `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` but not `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER`... If its going to follow a concept, it should've enforced it for functions too right? or am I wrong?

Comment: million dollar question to me right now, seeking the truth!

Comment: I think maybe other object can depend on a trigger and If you delete the trigger it deletes other objects too (in case of cascade).

Comment: This is not true. I can not drop view because of `ERROR:  cannot drop view currency_rate because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  composite type consume_info column currency_rate depends on type currency_rate`

Comment: @CrystalPaladin You cannot drop a function that is in use by another function. This `DROP` and `CREATE` technique wouldn't work for functions and that's why `CREATE OR REPLACE` exists.

Answer (score 143):

No way to create or replace a trigger but can do this way

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS yourtrigger_name on "yourschemaname"."yourtablename";
```

Comment: ..and then follow it up with the `CREATE TRIGGER...` query

Answer (score 32):

You should use two statements: one for drop trigger and another for creating a trigger.

Example:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_trigger
  ON my_schema.my_table;
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON my_schema.my_table
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_schema.my_function();
```

Comment: Slap `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` on there and you should be good.

Answer (score 18):

As of PostgreSQL 14, [`CREATE TRIGGER` now also supports "`OR REPLACE`"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html).

You can now use `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ...` (instead of using `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` first).

This also seems to handle the case of partitioned tables sensibly:

> Creating a row-level trigger on a partitioned table will cause an identical “clone” trigger to be created on each of its existing partitions; and any partitions created or attached later will have an identical trigger, too. If there is a conflictingly-named trigger on a child partition already, an error occurs unless CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER is used, in which case that trigger is replaced with a clone trigger. When a partition is detached from its parent, its clone triggers are removed.

Also noteworthy:

> Currently, the OR REPLACE option is not supported for constraint triggers.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function` with the following script in your SQL:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.triggers
    WHERE event_object_table = 'table_name'
    AND trigger_name = 'trigger_name'
  )
  THEN
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();
  END IF;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use below code.

```
DO $$ BEGIN

CREATE (trigger, type , ...);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN null;
END $$;
```

sample:

```
DO $$ BEGIN

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_workIDExist
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "GalleryModel"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_workIDExist();

EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN null;
END $$;
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a Python script which extracts all triggers from a postgresql dump file for a rebuild. I use many stacked views which works nicely with QGIS; this helped maintenance of the dependent views a lot.

Based on Ali Bagheri's great answer.

```py
import pathlib
import re
import sys

re_pat_str = r'^\s*CREATE TRIGGER.*?;\s*$'

sql_wrapper_str = """
DO $$ BEGIN
{trigger_str}
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN null;
END $$;
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
  sql_file = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1])
  with sql_file.open("r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    sql_str = f.read()

  re_pat = re.compile(re_pat_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

  parts = []
  for i, m in enumerate(re_pat.finditer(sql_str)):
    parts.append(sql_wrapper_str.format(trigger_str=m[0].strip()))

  new_sql_str = "\n".join(parts)
  new_sql_file = sql_file.parent / f'{sql_file.stem}.trigger{sql_file.suffix}'
  with new_sql_file.open("w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(new_sql_str)
```