# Trigger error (create trigger)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I've got the error :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "trigger"
>   LINE 18: CREATE OR REPLACE trigger T1  
>   ERROR: syntax error at or near "trigger"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 391

for this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigf1() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT*
        FROM Receipt JOIN Sells ON Receipt.license = Sells.license
        WHERE iname = NEW.iname AND cid = NEW.cid AND rno = NEW.rno
    )THEN
    RETURN NEW; 
ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'This cafe does not sell the item: %s',new.iname;
    RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T1  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  
ON Buys
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf1();
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: remove the `OR REPLACE` from the `CREATE TRIGGER` line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927365/create-or-replace-trigger-postgres

Comment: I removed the `OR REPLACE` from both `CREATE TRIGGER` and `CREATE FUNCTION` but I still got the error.

Comment: @ShiraAsulin if you stilll get error, please paste new error message - syntax in 2nd command is invalid, after removing 'OR REPLACE' part it should work

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bottom call back to a procedure based on comments.  I noticed that there was no space between select and *.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigf1() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * -- added a space after the select
        FROM Receipt JOIN Sells ON Receipt.license = Sells.license
        WHERE iname = NEW.iname AND cid = NEW.cid AND rno = NEW.rno
    )THEN
    RETURN NEW; 
ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'This cafe does not sell the item: %s',new.iname;
    RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T1  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  
ON Buys
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf1();
```

Comment: I've changed to function but still getting the error.

Comment: The only allowed trigger syntax is `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` - and there is no distinction between functions and procedures in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ShiraAsulin If tis doesn't work try running the begin ... end; statements outside of the trigger.  Just try running them in a console so you can make sure the syntax of the trigger body is correct.